# Usage of for-each iteration and declaration of iteration variable externally

Tags: java, foreach

I just noticed that the declaration of the iteration variable cannot be done outside of the for each alike to the case of traditional for loop.

Say for eg, the following below is not possible:

```
String str;
for(str : strings) {
  // Do something
}
```

But with traditional for loop, I could declare the iteration loop control variable outside too, so that I can reuse it or for getting the last value outside of the loop.

```
int i;
for(; i < strings.length; i++) {
  // Do something
}
System.out.println("I iterated upto " + i);
```

Why such a restriction is kept for for-each loop construct?  I agree that the iteration variable can get a value only from with in the for-each loop. But why not use it externally to keep and use it for a default value or the last element value from the loop? However, this restriction looks so naive and felt like something of my liberty before to that is taken out.  If such a thing was possible, I would have written a code like this:

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"First", "Middle", "Last"};
String str = "Default";
for(str : strings) {
  // Do something.
}
if(str.equals("Last") {
 System.out.println("I did a for each iteration and my last value is " + str);
} else {
 System.out.println("I couldn't iterate, so what I can show you is " + str);
}
```

So that, if my strings array is empty, I would see a graceful message as "I couldn't iterate, so what I can show you is Default".  If my string array is having the elements as above, I could see the message as "I did a for each iteration and my last value is Last" without an additional boolean variable to check for whether I went inside the loop or not.

Also do to this enforcing of iteration variable declaration, I am facing another problem with namespace conflicts too:

```
String string = "Hello";
-----------------------
-----------------------
for(String string : strings) {  // I am forced to use a different name for string, though I prefer to use as a string only for my conventional semantics.
  // Do something
}
```

Some one might perceive that is as a personal taste.  However, the language construct could have been versatile enough whenever it is possible.  I don't see any valid reason for keeping this restriction of scope in particular for for-each.  Does it make sense?  Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: It's considered a good practise to declare variables with as limited scope as possible; IMO, re-using the variable outside of the for loop makes the code harder to read (and more error-prone).

Comment: I agree, but all I am saying is that, a language must not restrict me on such things.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll have to make use of a temporary variable, like so:

```
String tmp = "default";
for(String str : strings) {
    tmp = str;
    // Do something
}
//tmp here is the last used value in the loop
//And other stuff
```

**Note:** The name of the temporary variable you choose must be different than the loop variable.

As for the design choice of the loop, I think we have to chalk it up to a syntactic oversight (ironically on a symbol used as syntactic sugar) that you cannot pre-declare the value.

As per your second question, how would you differentiate between which `string` you're trying to reference?